# cvtColor returns exception

Tags: python, opencv, colors, spyder

I'm trying to perform a RGB to L*a*b* color convertion using cv2.cvtColor(image,cv.COLOR_RGB2LAB) but Spyder returns the following error :

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.dims <= 2 && esz <= (size_t)32) in transpose,
file /tmp/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1680 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /tmp/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:1680: error: (-215) src.dims <= 2 && esz <= (size_t)32 in function transpose
```

Here is the relevant my code, I am creating a numpy array using 3 channels for R, G and B which are all (300,400) sized array of type float64. This gives me a (300,400,3) array of float 64, called small_wbcorrect_lab

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2 as cv


width=400
height=300

small_wbcorrect_lab=np.zeros((np.size(range(0,width)),np.size(range(0,height)),3),dtype=np.float64) # create an array which will contain the converted l*a*b* image

# I skip the part of the code which fills the arrays redchannel_wbcorrect,greenchann... for more clarity. 
# They are all three (300,400) float64 array filled with values from 0 to 255

small_wbcorrect=np.transpose(np.array([np.transpose(redchannel_wbcorrect),np.transpose(greenchannel_wbcorrect),np.transpose(bluechannel_wbcorrect)])/255)

plt.imshow(small_wbcorrect)
plt.title('Photo White Balanced') # displaying works fine

small_wbcorrect_lab=cv.cvtColor(small_wbcorrect,cv.COLOR_RGB2LAB)
```

funny thing is : cv.cvtColor works nicely if I use it to convert an imported image, imported with

```
image=cv.imread('image.jpg')
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: The error seems to be in `np.transpose()`, don't you think?

Comment: I guess you're right, but cv.transpose also give an exception and I don't see how to create my array without those transposition

Comment: That might be because of the way your other matrices are created (or not created). You should try to display or check the properties of `redchannel_wbcorrect` and others. I tried this with some random values, it works.